# Balance Sheet and Profit Loss Consolidated view in Chart of Account with Multicurrency Exchange rates calculation

Tags: odoo-8

Below is my Multi-company configuration I have made in Odoo 8.

Company A - USD (Parent); 
Company B - INR (Child 1); 
Company C - EUR (Child 2);

I want Company A Chart of Accounts to consolidate B and C with respect the Currency Exchange rates that I have defined in the Currencies section.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's Bug in system, it will consolidate that amount assuming it's in same currency, same will be the problem on multi-currency invoice analysis view.

To slow this you can do.periodic manual journal entries cross companies so show consolidation,  this is manual way of doing but works.

Bests

Comment: Thank you 'firebug'.  But I am surprised that Odoo has not done this basic Multi-currency feature.  I am still hoping that anyone would have developed a module for this.   Looking forward for their inputs.

Comment: @Umar defentaly you will find something on community,  just goto : https://www.odoo.com/apps?search=multi+Company+